# Using row_number() as list index in mutate dplyr

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I'm trying to use the row_number() of my dataframe as an index for each row. The idea is to use this index to access a specific list element.

```
dataset <- data %>% 
      mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
      mutate(Y = strsplit(date, split = " ")[[index]][1])
```

In short, for every row, I want to use its row index to get a specific string element from another list.

This throws an index error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: recursive indexing failed at level 2 .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer this without any data or a reproducible example, so this is what I am *guessing* the author wants. (If yes, then the `index` variable is unnecessary and `dplyr::rowwise()` is what you need):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

iris[c(1:3),] %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(df = ., var = "index") %>%
  dplyr::rowwise(data = .) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
                Y = stringr::str_split(string = Species, pattern = "o")[[1]][1])
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   index Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Y    
#>   <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>
#> 1 1             5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa  set  
#> 2 2             4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa  set  
#> 3 3             4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa  set
```

Comment: Still: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no such index at level 1 .`

Comment: Should note: date is a column.

Comment: @incodeveritas Can you provide an example of what you want to do with a subset of your data or some other dataset in-built in R?

Comment: I ended up posting here with more information. row_wise() solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778309/dplyr-mutate-duplicates-list-values-when-trying-to-index

Comment: @incodeveritas That's the solution I had posted as well, of course just based on a guess of what you wanted.

Comment: I was a little thrown off by your syntax. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I should stop explicitly outlining all details of function arguments; makes for a confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this would also work:

```
dataset <- data %>% 
  mutate(Y = lapply(row_number(), function(x) strsplit(date, split = " ")[[x]][1]))
```