# Dplyr mutate duplicates list values when trying to index

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I start with a dataset like this (it's from Gallup). I want to pull the year and date out of the dataset and into a new column. So I try to split the date string...

```
index   date         R  D
1   2018 Jan 2-7    35  50  
2   2017 Dec 4-11   41  45  
3   2017 Nov 2-8    39  46  
4   2017 Oct 5-11   39  46  
5   2017 Sep 6-10   45  47  
6   2017 Aug 2-6    43  46
```

.. using mutate

```
dataset <- data %>% 
      mutate(Y = strsplit(date, split = " ")[[1]][1]) %>%
      mutate(M = strsplit(date, split = " ")[[1]][2])
```

But strsplit, rather than operate on the date row, seems to operate on a list of all column values.

So I end up with the [[1]] subset accessor just grabbing the first row value, rather than a the list entry relevant to each row.

```
index   date         R  D    Y        M
1   2018 Jan 2-7    35  3   2018    Jan
2   2017 Dec 4-11   41  3   2018    Jan
3   2017 Nov 2-8    39  3   2018    Jan
4   2017 Oct 5-11   39  3   2018    Jan
5   2017 Sep 6-10   45  3   2018    Jan
6   2017 Aug 2-6    43  3   2018    Jan
```

How can I split the string so an extrapolate the value from the list for each row? Using index as a subset accessor doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the package [`stringr`](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html), which is part of the tidyverse, and thus works seamlessly with dplyr.

```
data %>% mutate(Y = str_extract(date, "^\\d{4}"),
                M = str_extract(date, "[A-Za-z]{3}"))

#   index          date  R  D    Y   M
# 1     1  2018 Jan 2-7 35 50 2018 Jan
# 2     2 2017 Dec 4-11 41 45 2017 Dec
# 3     3  2017 Nov 2-8 39 46 2017 Nov
# 4     4 2017 Oct 5-11 39 46 2017 Oct
# 5     5 2017 Sep 6-10 45 47 2017 Sep
# 6     6  2017 Aug 2-6 43 46 2017 Aug
```

`str_extract` allows you to extract substrings based on a pattern -- here, we use two different regular expressions. The first matches 4 consecutive digits (`\\d{4}`) at the start of the string (`^`). The second expression simply takes 3 consecutive letters (`[A-Za-z]`), which is safe given the structure of your dates.

If you'd still like to use `strsplit` with `mutate`, however, you can add a call to `rowwise`:

```
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Y = strsplit(date, split = " ")[[1]][1],
                              M = strsplit(date, split = " ")[[1]][2])
```

Comment: Ended up needing rowwise(), used that solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `extract` function from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) with capturing groups.

```
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  extract(date, into = c("Y", "M"), regex = "(\\d{4}) ([A-Za-z]{3})", remove = FALSE)
dat2
#   index          date    Y   M  R  D
# 1     1  2018 Jan 2-7 2018 Jan 35 50
# 2     2 2017 Dec 4-11 2017 Dec 41 45
# 3     3  2017 Nov 2-8 2017 Nov 39 46
# 4     4 2017 Oct 5-11 2017 Oct 39 46
# 5     5 2017 Sep 6-10 2017 Sep 45 47
# 6     6  2017 Aug 2-6 2017 Aug 43 46
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "index   date         R  D
1   '2018 Jan 2-7'    35  50  
                  2   '2017 Dec 4-11'   41  45  
                  3   '2017 Nov 2-8'    39  46  
                  4   '2017 Oct 5-11'   39  46  
                  5   '2017 Sep 6-10'   45  47  
                  6   '2017 Aug 2-6'    43  46",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```